# Multilingual Dates where date format varies

Tags: templating, date, localization

I have a multilingual site, and I want my dates formatted like:

- English site: July 13, 2014
- Italian site: 13 lulgio 2014

So the month name is translated, and the order of the elements changes as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Craft has extended Twig's [date filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html) so that it translates the output (no documentation for this, but the code is in *craft/app/etc/templating/twigextensions/CraftTwigExtension.php* around line 152). So `{{now|date('F j, Y')}}` will give **July 13, 2014** on the English site, and **luglio 13, 2014** on the Italian site. Which is half way there. In order to get the Italian date to use the Italian format (*j F Y*), we need a translation for the format string. Add this to *craft/translations/it.php*. (For more info see [Static Translations](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/static-translations)):

```
'F j, Y' => 'j F Y',
```

To output the translated date:

```
{{now|date('F j, Y'|t)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to customized the output you can also use the Crafts datetime methods [`localeDate()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/datetime#localeDate) and [`localeTime()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/datetime#localeDate) to return a date / time in the current locale's preferred date format.

```
{# Returns '7/15/2014' if current locale is 'en' #}
{# Returns '15.07.2014' if current locale is 'it' #}
{{ now.localeDate() }
```

Comment: How do you set the preferred format for the locale?

Comment: I don't think you can, @Marion. That's why your approach is better if you have a need to customize the output.